# Is there anyway to dynamically add column in a SQL Server table based on current year?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had a SQL Server table with columns:

```
target_2011, target_2012, target_2013, target_2014, target_2015
```

Is there any way to add a dynamic column `target_2016` to the table as soon as we enter into the year 2016, based on the current year?

Comment: This is a bad design. You should not create values as dynamic columns, you should create column to hold dynamic values.

Comment: Could you?  You could, I suppose, create an agent job that runs once a year and issues the appropriate DDL.  I'd hate to have a job that runs once a year because that's the sort of thing that is very easy to break inadvertently.  The underlying data model appears incorrect.  It would make much more sense to have multiple rows with a `year_num` column that has values like 2014, 2015, 2016, etc.  Then your data model doesn't have to change when the new year arrives.

Comment: Unfortunately it was designed like that, and a lot of data exists in the table currently. So, instead of disturbing it, I thought of this idea.

Comment: In principle you can create job that check date and make ALTER TABLE. But I don't think it's a good idea. Or maybe you mean not table but PIVOT report?

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin Cave. We have been following that kind of procedures for the rest of project. Unfortunately, this table has not that kind of structure.

Comment: What you have here is called _technical debt_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a SQL agent job with

```
DECLARE @column varchar(20), @SQL varchar(1000)
SET @column = 'target_'+CAST(year(getdate()) AS varchar(4))
SET @SQL = 
'ALTER TABLE <yourtable>
ADD '+@column+' varchar(50)'
EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

Now schedule this job to run at 00:01 on the 1st of January every year.

While this will do what you are looking for, I agree with the observations in the comment section. This is an inherently bad design and not a good idea at all.